# it's possible to call two methods in one soap request?

Tags: php, soap

I create a simple wsdl and soap server with some methods. Now I want to ask you if is possible to call two methods with one soap request?

ex.

```
$server->_call(array=>('methodOne','methodTwo', $args);
```

or i must send two soap request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Message batching is a non-goal of SOAP](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383487). You will have to send two requests.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. However, since you created the server, you can can simply add higher-level methods :

```
// low level
method1($args){
    prepare_A();
}

// low level
method2($args){
    finish_A();
}

// higher level
method3($args){
    method1($args);
    method2($args);
}
```